# Python else issues making an FTP program

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax, ftp, try-catch

I am having an issue with the else statement of this program... I have checked my spacing and it seems to be correct.  I keep getting syntax error on the else statement.  The program creates and file then attempts to upload it to a ftp server but if it fails to not say anything to the user and just continue It will try again when the program loops.  Any help you could provide would be greatly appreciated.

```
#IMPORTS
import ConfigParser
import os
import random
import ftplib
from ftplib import FTP
#LOOP PART 1
from time import sleep
while True:
    #READ THE CONFIG FILE SETUP.INI
    config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
    config.readfp(open(r'setup.ini'))
    path = config.get('config', 'path')
    name = config.get('config', 'name')
    #CREATE THE KEYFILE
    filepath = os.path.join((path), (name))
    if not os.path.exists((path)):
        os.makedirs((path))
    file = open(filepath,'w')
    file.write('text here')
    file.close()
    #Create Full Path
    fullpath = path + name
    #Random Sleep to Accomidate FTP Server
    sleeptimer = random.randrange(1,30+1)
    sleep((sleeptimer))
    #Upload File to FTP Server
    try:
        host = '0.0.0.0'
        port = 3700
        ftp = FTP()
        ftp.connect(host, port)
        ftp.login('user', 'pass')
        file = open(fullpath, "rb")
        ftp.cwd('/')
        ftp.storbinary('STOR ' + name, file)
        ftp.quit()
        file.close()
        else:
            print 'Something is Wrong'
    #LOOP PART 2
    sleep(180.00)
```

Comment: Did you mean `except`?!

Comment: It was my understanding that I needed to use else... I am a bit of a newbie when it comes to programing

Comment: May I recommend https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: 1. Replace `else:` with `except Exception:` 2. `except Exception:` should be at the same indentation level as `try:`

Comment: Thanks that did the trick... I apologize for the question but this is new territory for me... thanks again

Answer (score 2):

`else` is valid as part of an exception block, but it is only run if an exception is not raised and there must be a `except` defined before it.

*(edit)* Most people skip the else clause and just write code after exiting (dedenting) from the  try/except clauses.

The quick tutorial is:

```
try:
    # some statements that are executed until an exception is raised
    ...
except SomeExceptionType, e:
    # if some type of exception is raised
    ...
except SomeOtherExceptionType, e:
    # if another type of exception is raised
    ...
except Exception, e:
    # if *any* exception is raised - but this is usually evil because it hides
    # programming errors as well as the errors you want to handle. You can get
    # a feel for what went wrong with:
    traceback.print_exc()
    ...
else:
    # if no exception is raised
    ...
finally:
    # run regardless of whether exception was raised
    ...
```